# Sexual Powers Hadith

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity

I have read a hadith somewhere which says something like

> Anas bin Malik said, "The Prophet used to visit all his wives in a
> round, during the day and night and they were eleven in number." I
> asked Anas, "Had the Prophet the strength for it?" Anas replied, "We
> used to say that the Prophet was given the strength of thirty (men)."
> And Sa`id said on the authority of Qatada that Anas had told him about
> nine wives only (not eleven)

Is this hadith authentic?

Comment: This is authentic but it is one of those hadith that is misinterpreted. I will post my brief answer explaining it rightly. So please make sure you check my answer, okay?

Comment: The hadith is regarded as authentic because it is mentioned in Sahih al-Bukhari, but it is a hadith on which there's a disputed especially contemporary scholars raised on the content.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - Thanks for commenting. May I know what kind of dispute was raised? Dispute regarding its authenticity?

Comment: @Ren one could say the second version of Sahih al-Bukhari has a less reliable narrator, but that isn't the point of discussion. Some "scholars" rather found such an information as rather disrespectful or giving a strange, wrong or bad picture of our prophet. Further this "hadith" nowhere confirms that the prophet did so, as it is a report of Anas a young men of between 10-21 years. Certainly in the hadith commentaries scholars discussed what might be regarded as a bad picture saying that this statement doesn't say that he () used to do so regularly as he also used to perform salat al-Layl.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - I really like the point you raised about Salah- al-layl. I will be posting my answer soon about this in the answer section of this post, and I would appreciate it if you can mention the name of scholars who had doubts about the Matn of this particular hadith.

Comment: @Ren this was mentioned at least by a rather non scholar Gamal al-Bana - see the is Sahih al-Bukhari 100% sahih post. I'm not sure whether any known scholar addresed it. I may need to check whether Muhammad al-Ghazaly did so.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - Yes, brother. Please check it and please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - Moreover, I am also investigating the saying of Anas, "We used to say that the Prophet was given the strength of thirty (men)". I do not think that whatever a Sahabahi says is a factual thing, according to Hadith, don't you agree?

Comment: Any updates about this post?

Comment: @Ren Hy i am not sure i am correct but ive found out while doing research about this hadith is that this hadith was not controversial pre 20 century for example ibn jawzi used this hadith to criticisze ghazali! he said something like 'why do you say this while Prophet used to have intercourse with all his wives in a single night (using this hadith)'. ibn hajar also said nothing about this hadith i think

Comment: @jibnj - Can you provide me with the sources that state that Ibn Jawzi used his Hadith to criticize Ghazali? So this means discussing things like virility of a person were not considered offensive? Qurtubi also made such remarks about Prophet Solomon in his commentary. He stated that Prophet Solomon had the strength of 40 Prophets. Jami Al-Usul says that Prophets of Allah were endowed with great sexual potency and virility because the light of faith flows into the veins and this faith fuels physical strength. There are some daif Riwayah of Prophet (SAW) defeating Rukanah in a wrestling match.

Comment: @Ren in his book the devil deception (talbis iblis), page323

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Asalaam Alaikum**

the hadith you have mentioned is narrated in sahih bukhari and it is one of the most authentic works of hadith. below is a link for reference;

https://sunnah.com/bukhari:268

there is another narration in bukhari,

see : https://sunnah.com/bukhari:284

both these hadith are graded 'sahih' (authentic).

and there is one more similar hadith narrated in sunan an-nasai and it is also sahih.

see : https://sunnah.com/nasai:3198

---

may Allah the mighty and sublime grant you mercy and guide you to the straight path.

**Allah knows best**